# Adding new property to existing javascript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, foreach, properties

I am trying to add format: "film" to each object in the array but I can't figure it out.

```
var movie = [
    {title: "A Clockwork Orange", year: "1971", raiting: "8.3", genre: "Crime, Drama, Sci-Fi"},
    {title: "Full Metal Jacket", year: "1987", raiting: "8.3", genre: " Drama, War"},
    {title: "Pulp Fiction", year: "1994", raiting: "8.9", genre: "Crime, Drama"},
    {title: "Fight Club", year: "1999", raiting: "8.8", genre: "Drama"},
    {title: "Interstellar", year: "2014", raiting: "8.6", genre: "Adventure, Drama, Sci-Fi"}
];


movie.forEach(function () {
    movie.format = "film";
});


movie.forEach(function (element) {
    console.log(element);
});
```

Comment: Just something to keep in mind for the future, using a `for ... in` or `for ... of` loop gives you a lot less headache when it comes to scoping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass an argument to `function` and add the new property to it

```
movie.forEach(function (element) {
    element.format = "film";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `goes to` operator.

```js
var movie = [    {title: "A Clockwork Orange", year: "1971", raiting: "8.3", genre: "Crime, Drama, Sci-Fi"},    {title: "Full Metal Jacket", year: "1987", raiting: "8.3", genre: " Drama, War"},    {title: "Pulp Fiction", year: "1994", raiting: "8.9", genre: "Crime, Drama"},    {title: "Fight Club", year: "1999", raiting: "8.8", genre: "Drama"},    {title: "Interstellar", year: "2014", raiting: "8.6", genre: "Adventure, Drama, Sci-Fi"}];

let i = movie.length;
while (i --> 0) movie[i].format = 'film';
console.log(movie);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are into ES6 too, you can certainly do this with the fat arrow.

```
movie.forEach(element => element.format = "film");
```